# Bootstrap 4, Form-Inline does not align on XS view

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Using Boostrap 4, I have a .form-inline at the footer of my page. It looks fine when the viewport is larger than the XS breakpoint...

[image: Larger than XS]

...but then breaks when entering XS view...

[image: XS or smaller]

...from my understanding, the subscribe button should drop below the input field on XS view.

Here is the code that I used...

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-first order-md-6 align-self-center">

    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">

        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="email" class="form-control mr-2 mb-2" id="EmailInpue" placeholder="Join our Mailing List" />

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> &nbsp;Subscribe</button>

    </form>

</div>
```

...I managed to get what I wanted by putting the button in the same form-group div as the input...

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-first order-md-6 align-self-center">

    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">

        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="email" class="form-control mr-2 mb-2" id="EmailInpue" placeholder="Join our Mailing List" />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> &nbsp;Subscribe</button>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

...but from my understanding of the Bootstrap format is that the button should usually be outside of that form-group.

Anyways, this seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: hey dude add your code in order to look into it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have known better; I have added the code, although I seem to have found a fix for it, albeit a fix that should not have worked from my understanding and experience with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put the `buttons` in the same `form-group` as the `input` because `form-group`, by default, has only `margin-bottom`.

There are a few ways to fix this issue.

1. Put the `button` in a `form-group`.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> &nbsp;Subscribe</button>
</div>
```

2. Keep your code as it is but remove the `margin-bottom` of the `form-group`.

```html
<div class="form-group mb-0">
```

I'd go for the last approach.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-first order-md-6 align-self-center">

  <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">

    <div class="form-group mb-0">

      <input type="email" class="form-control mr-2 mb-2" id="EmailInpue" placeholder="Join our Mailing List" />

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> &nbsp;Subscribe</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the button code in the same form-group div as the input field seems to have worked...

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 order-first order-md-6 align-self-center">

    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">

        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="email" class="form-control mr-2 mb-2" id="EmailInpue" placeholder="Join our Mailing List" />

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"><i class="far fa-envelope-open"></i> &nbsp;Subscribe</button>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```